# Confused about return by reference

Tags: c++, return-by-reference

I am confused by the following example:

```
class complex {
  double re, im;
public:
  complex(double r, double i) : re{r}, im{I} ()

  complex& operator+= (const complex&z) { re += z.re; im += z.im; return *this; }
};
```

I don't understand why the return type from the `operator +=` is by reference, since `re` and `im` are getting updated. I also do not understand why `*this` is included.

Comment: I don't understand why you think that `re` and `im` getting updated has anything to do with the return type. `return *this;` is there because `*this` is the object that the function is returning a reference to.

Answer (score 1):

It could as well return `void`.

The C++ convention is that `operator+=` returns a reference to its left-hand operand, so that you can write an expression like `if((x += y) > 10)`.

Comment: Could you please explain why it's necessary to return a reference for if((x+=y)>10 please? Sorry, I'm just new to all of this.

Comment: @MichaelHutton  If it returns `void`, then you can just use `+=` to do plus and update the value. As it returns `void`, you can do nothing more. If it return the reference of *this, you can use the value immediately. Such as a+=b = c, or (a+=b)>c etc. They mean a = a + b; a = c; and a = a+ b; a > c.

Comment: Ahhh, now I get it! Thanks for this info

Answer (score 1):

By convention, we try that `operator` for class works as for built-in.

and

```
int i = 0;
(i += 40) += 2;
```

is valid.

So returning by reference allows that for classes.

Answer (score 0):

First:

Your operator += is not properly declared. It should be

```
complex& operator+=(complex const& other){...}
```

Second to answer your actual question, you are returning *this because the += operator is a compound assignment operator which is modifying the internal state of the variable being assigned to. So you return a reference to the variable that "this" is pointing to.

Comment: The code was taken directly from the book The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup (The creator of C++)

Comment: not properly? May we know why? const T & and T const & are the same right?

Comment: An edit to the question fixed the declaration since this answer was posted.

Comment: the deceleration was missing the () and arguments within, and has since been corrected